# how to execute a single unit test case using activator?

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, typesafe-activator

we are using play framework and activator as a build tool,we have many unit test cases written in out project,can you please tell me how to run single unit test case using activator ?
i tried running this command in command line

> activator test-only SampleNodeServiceImplTest.

but this command is running all the test cases in the project.
but i want to run only one specific unit test case.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you have to enclose the argument to `activator` in quotes, that is, `activator "test-only package.SampleNodeServiceImplTest"` should work (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/xGDhQSz5cTs).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of **test-only** you can also use **testOnly** as follow

activator "testOnly package.SampleNodeServiceImplTest".

Giving the the full package path also very important